# How do I place a <hr> beside an image?

Tags: html, css

In my fiddle you will see a break in text, I would like to put a `<hr>` there and decorate it in the CSS, but I have no idea how to do this as when I do this it breaks my inline-block, and I'm thinking that's because the `<hr>` is a block element. Is there any creative solutions around this? I need it to be fixed there between the two paragraphs of text to maintain responsiveness.

Thanks!

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z5VAh/)

HTML:

```
<section>
    <div class="first">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut rutrum, nisl id ultricies sollicitudin, neque sapien porta nisl, ut gravida elit quam id nisi. <br /><br />Nunc viverra laoreet porttitor. Duis augue justo, pellentesque a luctus eget, luctus a quam. Fusce nec neque nec dolor mattis tempor id vitae nisi.</p>
        <img class="ipad" src="http://img1.lesnumeriques.com/news/26/26963/ipad-4-os.jpg">
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.first {
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 0;
}

.first p {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49%;
}

.ipad {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49.2%;
}

 p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em 0;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

Comment: How about `border-bottom` instead of a `<hr>`?

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand That's a good idea except when I break up the paragraph tags or add another p tag then it messes with my vertical align. Are you able to put your idea into a fiddle?

Comment: You want it in between the paragraphs, correct?

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand Yes, please.

Comment: Looks like @Serlite has a good solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve this by wrapping your `<p>` and `<hr>` elements into another `<div>` element, and making it `display:inline-block`. My solution involved adding this wrapper so your structure ended up being:

```
<section>
    <div class="first">
        <div class="text-wrap">
            <p></p>
            <hr />
            <p></p>
        </div>
        <img class="ipad" src="http://img1.lesnumeriques.com/news/26/26963/ipad-4-os.jpg" />
    </div>
</section>
```

(Additional element is `.text-wrap`. Note that I split up the two paragraphs into individual `<p>` elements.) The CSS I left mostly alone, except I removed the definition for `.first p`, and added these two:

```
.text-wrap{
    vertical-align: middle;
    display:inline-block;
    width:49%;
}
.text-wrap p {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/z5VAh/2/) that shows what this achieves. If this isn't what you were looking for, or you wanted to use a different method, let me know and I'll be happy to help further!

Comment: Great! I'm glad I could help you out.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative to Serlite's answer.  It basically puts the `<hr>` in implicitly, using CSS.

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z5VAh/3/)

We add a border to the top of each paragraph, except the first one in each container.

```
p {
    ...
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}

p:nth-child(1) {
    border-top: none;
}
```

Comment: And presumably I can just target the .first p and this will work?

Comment: Yeah.  You can just put `.first ` before each of the selectors.